# How do I set xldirection by string variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to control direction of the search of Range().End(xldirection).  How do I set the xldirection with a variable?

```
    Dim D As Range
    Dim aa As String
    Set D = Range("$A$1")
    
    aa = "xldown"
    f = Range(D, D.End(aa))
```

I expected it to grab an entire range.

Comment: They aren't strings they are numbers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection

Comment: You could do `Dim aa As Long` but more specific is `Dim aa As XlDirection`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end). You usually don't memorize rarely needed stuff (at least I don't).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Enum`eration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection):

```
Dim aa As XlDirection
aa = xlDown
```

If you specifically are using a `String` variable, then one option is to create a dictionary that maps the `String` representation to the built-in constant.

```
' Requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Static Function Directions() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    d.Add "xlUp", xlUp
    d.Add "xlDown", xlDown
    d.Add "xlToLeft", xlToLeft
    d.Add "xlToRight", xlToRight
    
    Set Directions = d
End Function

Sub Whatever()
    Dim bb As String
    bb = "xlDown"
    
    Dim d As Range, f As Range
    Set d = Range("A1")
    
    Set f = Range(d, d.End(Directions(bb)))
End Sub
```

The `Static` keyword here is really overkill, but it allows for `d` within `Directions` to be created only once, and for it to maintain its values for as long as the program is running. It could just as easily be `Static d As Scripting.Dictionary` (where this would be the `Static` *statement*, not keyword). See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement) for more.

Or use a `Function`:

```
Public Function Direction(ByVal d As String) As XlDirection
    Select Case d
        Case "xlUp"
            Direction = xlUp
        Case "xlDown"
            Direction = xlDown
        Case "xlToLeft"
            Direction = xlToLeft
        Case "xlToRight"
            Direction = xlToRight
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Since you dug yourself in so deep and used the `Static` keyword, could you share a sentence or two about it? I've never used it with a procedure, I didn't even know that that's a possibility.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - added. Probably should have just kept it as the statement, i.e. `Static d As Scripting.Dictionary`, but whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The other day, I saw something similar, like `Property Directions...` and it started with `If Not Directions Is Nothing Then`. I wonder what's the difference. Just thinking out loud, I don't (didn't) want to torture you. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Not at all torture! I'm glad that you and others are around to keep me on my toes!